# How to find the text inside that are not contained inside braces

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text like `test{0:##}test2{Order:C}test3`.  I need to use regex and find the text `test` , `test2` , `test3` which are not inside the `{...}`.

For text inside the curly braces {0:##} i used

```
@"{0:(.*?)}"
```

But trying for text not inside the Curly braces, facing some difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of matching everything outside the braces (as suggested by Joey), it might be easier to split the string into an array, by an expression that matches only the braces.

```
result = Regex.Split(teststring, "\{[^}]*\}");
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are no nested braces you can use something like the following:

```
(?<=^|})[^{]+(?={|$)
```

This uses lookbehind and lookahead to find snippets embedded in `}...{` or delimited by the start or end of the string on one end.

Quick PowerShell test:

```
PS> [regex]::Matches('test{0:##}test2{Order:C}test3', '(?<=^|})[^{}]+(?={|$)') | select Value

Value
-----
test
test2
test3
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text is always in the same format why don't you use the `Split` function?